# Rendering an animation, all works except frame 2?

Tags: rendering

I made a text into video, and put in a melting part in there (fluid sim). I tweaked it to keep my PC from blowing up until I have that 8 core.

In the media player in Blender all shows up great.
In the render preview it all shows up great.
When I press the animate button it looks how I want it to look.

Then, on frame 2, it will get stuck in synchronizing the task for ever. So I manually went to frame 3 and that works as well.
Start the animation render from frame 3 to 200 and it all runs.

The only frame not rendering is frame 2. There must be something of at that frame but no idea what that could be.
(Since as far as I know all settings are the same from frame 1 until the last frame 300.)

res 512. render to PNG 16bit.

Who has an idea where it might get stuck on?

Answer (score 2):

This could be a cache problem. Try to delete the particle cache - add a new one, then delete the old one, to be sure. Jump to the last frame in your animation, and click *Update All To Frame*.